# Why is the file contents not showing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

so basically im trying to make it so when i select owl hub from the drop down tab that it will open the file but for some reason it isnt opening the file ive from what ive seen have formatted it correctly

```
 from tkinter import *

hf = Tk()
hf.geometry('150x300')

def uni2():
    uni3 = Toplevel(hf)
    variable = StringVar(uni3)
    variable.set("Select")
    a = variable.get()
    def subm():
        sci = Toplevel(uni3)
        lbl = Label(sci,text='N/A')
        lbl.pack()
        owl_hub = open('owlhub.txt','r')
        if a == "owlHub":
            lbl.config(text = owl_hub.readlines())

    sub = Button(uni3,text='submit',command=subm)
    uni4 = OptionMenu(uni3,variable,"owlHub")
    sub.pack()
    uni4.pack()
def pf1():
    pf2 = Toplevel(hf)




uni1 = Button(hf,text='universal',font=('verdana', 10), width = 16, command=uni2)
pf = Button(hf,text='Phantom forces',font=('verdana', 10), width = 16, command=pf1)
uni1.pack()
pf.pack()
hf.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `subm` is being called? Have you verified that `a` is what you're assuming it is? Have you verified that `owl_hub.readlines()` returns what you expect it to return?

Comment: ***when i select owl hub ... it will open the file***:  Where is your callback to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I found that I must use

```
variable.set("owl hub")
```

because select isn't in the selection list.

Comment: But you want: ***when i select owl hub from the drop down***. Now you have preselect it only.